# What does this notation mean. (Asymptotic approximation, from Hardy's Number Theory textbook)

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

From *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, Hardy, 6th ed*, on Page 9, it says,

> We may also observe that $f$ ~ $\phi$ is equivalent to $f = \phi + o(\phi)$ or to
>
> $f= \phi{\{1 + o(1)\}}$
>
> In these circumstances we say that $f$ and $\phi$ are asymptotically equivalent...

So what does $f= \phi{\{1 + o(1)\}}$ mean? I am especially confused about the brackets.

Thanks!

Comment: $f=\phi{\{1 + o(1)\}}$ means $f=\phi + o(\phi)$ as a form of factorisation.  It says $f$ is $\phi$ times something which is asymptotically equivalent to $1$, i.e. $\frac f \phi \sim 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a weird and non-standard choice of brackets, but clearly means nothing more than $φ(1+o(1)) = φ+φ·o(1) = φ+o(φ)$.